# View not rendering on NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm running a project in NET Core 2.1.1 with Visual Studio 2017 and I have the following problem:

**A view is not generating the corresponding HTML.**

I have the following controller:

```
public class CountryController : Controller {
    IUnitOfWork Context;
    IRepository<Country> countryRepository;

    public CountryController(IUnitOfWork context) {
        countryRepository = context.GetRepository<Country>();
        Context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult Index() {

        CountryViewModel countries = new CountryViewModel(countryRepository.Elements());
        return View(countries);
    }

    public IActionResult Insert (CountryBindingModel country) {
        Country Country = new Country();
        Country.Name = "Canada";
        countryRepository.Insert(Country);
        Context.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
}
```

I have the associated view:

```
@using Domain.Models

@model CountryViewModel

<form asp-controller="Country" asp-action="Insert">
    <label asp-for="Name"></label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Name"/>
    <button type="submit">Add Country</button>
</form>
<ul>
    @foreach (var a in Model.Countries) {
        <li>@(a.Name)</li>;
    }
</ul>
```

The HTML it generates is the following, taken from the browser, and it does not work to add the country:

```
<form asp-controller="Country" asp-action="Insert">
    <label asp-for="Name"></label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Name"/>
    <button type="submit">Add Country</button>
</form>
<ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag helpers are opt-in, and require you to import them for them to work.

Make sure you have a file named _ViewImports.cshtml in your Views folder, and make sure it adds the namespaces of helpers that you want.

For example, for all default MS helpers use the following:

```
@using AuthoringTagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, AuthoringTagHelpers
```